# What does this mean: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm afraid I just don't know what this error means, besides that there is an error.  I was able to build jars before, but this is my first time using the rpm-maven-plugin.

I would like to create an rpm, but so far using the rpm-maven-plugin has resulted in errors.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin
POM Location: C:\Users\<my name>\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\rpm-maven-plug
in\2.0.1\rpm-maven-plugin-2.0.1.pom

Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin at C:\U
sers\<my name>\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\rpm-maven-plugin\2.0.1\rpm-maven
-plugin-2.0.1.pom
```

Comment: Please post your full pom file and not only excerpts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was exactly as the error stated.  I went to my respository and opened the POM file at the path above.  I realize that somehow the POM file was downloaded while I was not authenticated against one of our internal systems.

So even though a file existed, the pom file only contained an error message.

After deleting the file at the path and restarting the build, the build was successful.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was missing the `~/.m2/settings.xml` file. Once I got that file, I was able to use maven just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this may be 2 fold:

1. There's a problem with the POM
2. You are running the wrong version of maven

Fix the POM or fix your Maven version.