# Create a zip file using maven

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to use the assembly plugin in order to create a zip file for a specific module of a multi-module Maven project. 
This module cointains only a bunch of xml and xsl files that needs to be packaged as a zip file (the folder's structure is saved under src/main/resources).

So I created the pom below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
<groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>myserver</artifactId>
<version>${myserver.version}</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>zip-sample</artifactId>
  <name>Sample zip</name>
  <version>${myserver.version}</version>
  <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>bin</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <id>create-distribution</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

but I get the error:

```
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin': Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin at /home/gundam/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.3/maven-assembly-plugin-2.3.pom
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1557)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.bindPluginToLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1503)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.constructLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1282)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin': . for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin at /home/gundam/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.3/maven-assembly-plugin-2.3.pom
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultPluginManager.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyVersionedPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultPluginManager.java:1642)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin at /home/gundam/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.3/maven-assembly-plugin-2.3.pom
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1599)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1571)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultPluginManager.java:277)
    ... 22 more
```

I tried to change the assembly plugin version, but I always the "Not a v4.0.0 POM" error even if the pom seems ok.

Maven's version used:

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_20
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_20/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.11.0-12-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Could it be a problem in the plugin definition inside the pom.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible that particular POM file is corrupt or mangled? Can you look at the contents of: /home/gundam/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.3/maven-assembly-plugin-2.3.pom

See here [What does this mean: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450277/what-does-this-mean-not-a-v4-0-0-pom-for-project-org-codehaus-mojorpm-maven-p) where someone has a similar issue.

Comment: Although it is useful; looks its not exact answer. It should go in as a comment.

Comment: Oops yes sorry, but I don't have enough reputation points to reply as a comment to his question. States I need "You must have 50 reputation to comment". Maybe you can comment the above to the question and I can delete this post.

Comment: keep your answer but improve it,

Comment: Indeed it was useful to check the file .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.3/maven-assembly-plugin-2.3.pom, it was mangled with HTML that says that the request got a HTTP 302 return code. I'll check the cause.