# Maven build Saiku failed. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM

Tags: java, maven, saiku

I am trying to develop Saiku. I have been following tutorial from [this page](http://wiki.meteorite.bi/display/SAIK/Development). I cloned from *git://github.com/OSBI/saiku.git* and is on master branch.

When I am trying to build by running

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

I am getting the following error:

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] BUILD ERROR [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
>
> Project ID: com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin POM Location:
>   /home/tareq/.m2/repository/com/samaxes/maven/minify-maven-plugin/1.7.4-modify/minify-maven-plugin-1.7.4-modify.pom
>
> Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project
>   com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin at
>   /home/tareq/.m2/repository/com/samaxes/maven/minify-maven-plugin/1.7.4-modify/minify-maven-plugin-1.7.4-modify.pom

The content of my *minify-maven-plugin-1.7.4-modify.pom* file is as follows:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 with Maven 2.2.1

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450277/what-does-this-mean-not-a-v4-0-0-pom-for-project-org-codehaus-mojorpm-maven-p

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I could successfully built by using Maven 3.

Comment: You should move your comment to the answer so its visible!